# Accessing Web Service in C# from Excel 2010

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to convert an Excel 2003 spread sheet using Soap Toolbox to access a web service in VBA, to Excel 2010 using VSOT in C#.

I have most of it working fine including accessing the web service in my C# code behind but accessing the web service from Excel is confusing me a little.

The spread sheet allows the client to run the web service 20 times at once instead of entering info 20 times online etc.

So theres a run button that simply does Application.CalculateFull which of course just forces the calculation of all data in the workbook.

In the cells that do the calcs, in the current VBA solution, they have the following - {=modulename.function($A£36:$A40,E1,E2 etc)}

This of course causes the web service to be called.

I have been fiddling about and just cant get the equivelent to work in my C# solution.

I have searched for this and cant seem to find the coding for the cell side of it.

Can someone please put me out of my misery and tell me what I am doing wrong, or even if this is still the correct way to do this !? :(

Cheers, George.

Comment: what is exact problem, is the modulename.function not getting called?

Comment: I just did all the work in the C# code using a loop. Seemed the better thing to do. Works great. I suspect it was more of a VBA solution.

Answer (score 0):

I just did all the work in the C# code using a loop. Seemed the better thing to do. Works great. I suspect it was more of a VBA solution